# Removing an Inactive Skype For Business Edge Pool

Tags: skype-for-business-2016

I've got an issue where I have 2 edge pools (EdgePoolA & EdgePoolB).
One of them (A new pool, EdgePoolB) has been created in the topology, and there are no old topology files to use.
Right now, I'm trying to delete EdgePoolB, but I get the following:

[image: Error Attached]

The EdgePoolB doesn't even have SkypeForBusiness services installed, and I'd like to remove it somehow, as it is making issues signing into Skype For Business.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this by doing the following:

1. Remove EdgePoolA from Skype for Business Topology.
2. Publish Topology.
3. Added new Edge Pool and configured it the same as EdgePoolA
   (Associated with the Front-End Pool instead of EdgePoolB)
4. Removed EdgePoolB from Skype for Business topology
5. Published toplogy
6. ran Export-csConfiguration
7. Ran Step 1, step 2 and step 3 on the EdgePoolA edge server.
8. Tested for replication and attempted sign in (was successful)

Now everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your front end and remove the edge server. VA in your front end and right click and edit properties. Find the edge server and delete it.